# Pinpointing an infinite recursion warning in R

Tags: r, rstudio, warnings, stack-trace

When I run my Shiny app in RStudio, I get this warning message:

```
Warning: Error in : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / 
options(expressions=)?
  90: <Anonymous>
```

I tried turning the warning into an error so that I could see it with

```
options(warn = 2)
```

but then RStudio crashes with "Fatal error".

I tried following the steps outlined here:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207601737-How-to-debug-a-fatal-error-

to attach lldb to the R process so that I could see a native stack trace, but attaching to the R process also causes RStudio to crash with "Fatal error".

I've restarted my R session and restarted RStudio to no avail.

My settings:

```
RStudio version 1.1.463
Debug -> On Error -> √ Error Inspector 
Tools -> Global Options
    [ ] Use debug error handler only when my code contains errors
Tools -> Global Options
    [ ] Automatically expand tracebacks in error inspector
```

How can I see at least part of a stack trace of the recursion?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see all the functions that are called, we can add a trace to every function in the global scope. I placed this before my call to `shinyApp(...)`:

```r
# ... files sourced here ... 

globalEnv <- globalenv()
# for some reason, this needs to be skipped
# or else we get an error about no stack trace
funcsToSkip <- c('server')
for (varName in ls(envir = globalEnv)) {
  if (varName %in% funcsToSkip) next
  varValue <- get(varName, envir = globalEnv)
  if (all(class(varValue) == "function")) {
    message(paste0("Tracing '", varName, "'"))
    trace(varName, where = globalEnv)
  }
}

shinyApp(...)
```

This allows me to see where it is recursing infinitely.